# GOOGLE web font loader

Tags: html, css, google-font-api, typekit

I've check many blogs, but couldn't find the answer to my question, currently I'm using the google web font loader To asynchronously load fonts from the google CDN, however, I am also making use of a  font stored locally on the server by  using the @font face declaration in my CSS.

Is it possible to combine the two, i.e. make the async script load google fonts from the CDN  and the local font (including FALLback)

// Here's the script in my HTML file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Merriweather:400,900italic,700italic,900,700:all' ] },
        custom: {
            families: ['Fira Sans'],
            urls: ['../assets/css/type.css']
        }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
          '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })(); 
    </script>

    <noscript>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,900italic,700italic,900,700&subset=all' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </noscript>
```

---

//Here is the local font declaration found in my CSS file

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'museo_sans300';
  src: url('museo/MuseoSans_300-webfont.eot?') format('eot'), url('museo/MuseoSans_300-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('museo/MuseoSans_300-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');}
```

I would like to make both of these load async and maybe even include  typekit in the future!

Is this possible?

Many thanks for your help